Nativescript Android stuck on splash screen
I am upgrading my nativescript app to support android 34 and facing this issue when app just stuck on splash screen and closes after a while.
here is my app.gradle file:-
// plugins {
//     id 'kotlin-kapt'
//     id 'kotlin-android'
// }
// apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

dependencies {
  implementation(name:'mobilertc', ext:'aar');
  implementation(name:'commonlib', ext:'aar');
  implementation(name:'zoomcustomactivity', ext:'aar');
  implementation(name:'ChatAppSDK-release',ext:'aar');




implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha05"
implementation "com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android:1.7.0"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.16.1"//
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.16.1"//
implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1"
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1"//
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.11.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0"
implementation "org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1"

implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.0.0"

implementation "androidx.window:window:1.0.0"

implementation "androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.10"//
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10"//

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2"//older version//
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2"//
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"//
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"//

implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"
// implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
// implementation "com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0"
implementation "androidx.webkit:webkit:1.6.0"


///////////
implementation "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.4"
implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.2"
implementation "com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.3.1.1@aar"
implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"
implementation "com.github.HBiSoft:PickiT:2.0.3"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.1"
implementation "com.salesforce.service:servicesdk:224.2.3"
implementation ("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0") {
    exclude group: "androidx.slidingpanelayout"
    exclude group: "androidx.asynclayoutinflater"
}

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.9"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.0"

// implementation "com.github.tapadoo:alerter:7.2.4"
// implementation "com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.13.3"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1"
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"

    configurations.all{
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
         exclude group: 'net.zetetic', module: 'android-database-sqlcipher'
          resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
            //force 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
          //  force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'
           // force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
           // force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
          }
    }
}

android {

  compileSdkVersion 34
  buildToolsVersion "34"
  // ndkVersion ""

  packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/*.so'
    }

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 34

    // Version Information
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    
    generatedDensities = []

    ndk {
      abiFilters.clear()
      //abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
      }

    multiDexEnabled true //important

  }

  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
  project.ext {
    useAndroidX = true
  }

   viewBinding {
    enabled = true
  }
  dexOptions {
     // jumboMode true
      javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
  }
      

}

repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools" }
  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

  // maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release" }
     
  maven {
    url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/salesforcesos.com/android/maven/release"
    content {
      // Does only include this group
      includeGroupByRegex "com.salesforce.*"
    }
  }

}


I tried removing some dependencies and found some are causing issue when used together and it works if I remove any few of them
if I remove any one group then it works but it doesn't work together
//group 1
implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.2"
implementation "com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.3.1.1@aar"

//group 2
implementation "com.github.tapadoo:alerter:7.2.4"
implementation "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.4"

//group 3
  implementation(name:'mobilertc', ext:'aar');
  implementation(name:'commonlib', ext:'aar');
//these are zoomSDK

